# Retrieve objects from indexes using angularfire2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm trying (with partial success :( ) to retrieve full objects as observables from a collection of indexes of my firebase RTDB using angularfire2 basic methods such as list() and object() in an Ionic app.
When retrieving the list of keys for the courses a user has enrolled on I make a new query and get the full data as an observable using the object() method. I get several null in the view when loading the page for the first time but the observables are still alive, so if I make a small change in those objects in the console, the whole object is retrieved and shown in the view without any problem. Am I missing something?

[Firebase RTDB root-level nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSY8m.png)

This is my page ts code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, List } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfileServiceProvider } from '../../providers/profile-service/profile-service';
import { MomentsFeedPage } from '../moments-feed/moments-feed';
import { CourseServiceProvider } from '../../providers/course-service/course-service';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
/**
 * Generated class for the MomentsPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-moments',
  templateUrl: 'moments.html',
})
export class MomentsPage{

  @ViewChild('enrolledList', { read: List }) enrolledList: List;
  public enrolledLis: Observable <{}>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public courseService: CourseServiceProvider,
    public userProfile: ProfileServiceProvider,
    public afDB: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {

    if(this.userProfile.currentUser) {
      console.log('constructor MomentsPage');
      this.enrolledLis = this.afDB.list('/userEnrollments/'+this.userProfile.currentUser.uid).snapshotChanges()
        .map( res => {
          let enrolled = res;
          let that = this;
          return enrolled.map(key => 
            that.courseService.getCourseDetail(key.key).snapshotChanges()
            .map(snap => 
               ({ key: snap.key, ...snap.payload.val() } )
            )
          )
        }
      );
    }

  }

  goToTopicsFeed(course: any) {
    this.navCtrl.push(MomentsFeedPage, {
      courseId: course.key, courseName: course.name, coursePic: course.coursePic
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MomentsPage');
  }

}
```

And this is the code for the view

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Moments</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content no-padding fullscreen parallax-header>
  <div class="header-image" style="background-image:url('./assets/imgs/lists/wishlist-1.jpg')">
    <h1>Moments</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <ion-list #enrolledList>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let course of enrolledLis | async" [attr.track]="(course|async)?.degree | courseTrackPipe ">
        <button ion-item (click)="goToTopicsFeed(course)" >
          <ion-thumbnail item-start>
            <img [src]="(course|async)?.coursePic || './assets/imgs/Film-set-greyscale.jpg'" alt="Course profile pic">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <h2>{{(course|async)?.name}}</h2>
          <h3>{{(course|async)?.degree}}</h3>
          <p>Topics info: #topics {{(course|async)?.topicsCount}} activity...</p>
        </button>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here you can see the behaviour:

[Partial processing of the observables (courses) during first call: css class in added so some rules are applied (border in blue or red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8I6I.png)

[The first object (course observable) was updated in the firebase console and updated without issues in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlQB4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I'll answer to myself: nothing wrong with the code, maybe I tested wrong. Anyway, there was something not so good in the code: returning async Observables may lead to some problems in the (click) action. Those can be solved using a *ngIf="course" block to make sure the object is got during runtime.